# How to get the first x elements of a char array in C? Is there an improved way with boost-libraries?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, boost, memcpy

My basic task is to get a subset of an buffer-array into another buffer array:

```
char buffer[max_len];

unit8 *pDestBuffer;
```

I used this code, because I would like to stay in ANSI-C:

```
memcpy(pDestBuffer, buffer, 4);
```

However - something must be wrong, because I don't get my result as I expect to. Because, when I debug buffer, I see all the *slots* of the array - when I do this with pDestBuffer, I get only one Item - which I can change however, with something like `memset(pDestBuffer,1,4)`

pDestBuffer is part of a structure, and the only other reference to it, besides the definition above, was were these lines:

```
requiredMemory = sizeof(Structure) + bufferSize;
pStructure = (Structure *)HostMalloc(requiredMemory);
pStructure->pDestBuffer = ((uint8 *)pStructure)+sizeof(Sturcture);
```

I know, this might be rather a basic task, and I am working on this myself, but please, if there is a "best-practice" for this or you know a solution, please share it with me.

As a twist, I would really like to know, if there might be an improved way for this, using the boost-libraries, which I do use anyways for other problems.

Comment: The title references C. The code is C. Your comment is "I would like to stay in ANSI-C". I see no reason for a C++ tag. I'll remove it.

Comment: @Robᵩ By that invalidating my answer. If OP comes out and confirms this, I'll delete it.

Comment: Because he wants to use boost. I have not seen any C libraries in boost, only C++ libraries.

Comment: Shoot, I skipped over the boost reference in the last paragraph. I'll put the tag back.

Comment: to clear it up - I have to mix C/C++ because I am designing something for windows/linux with serial-ports and GUIs - which is why I am using boost. But because this is to be ported on an embedded device, i'll like to stay in C for the essential code. It is messed up a bit, I know.

Comment: btw - thanks for all the quick responses - will have to take a minute to process all of this.

Comment: In general, `memcpy` is optimized for copying data.  For small quantities, you may have more efficiency by copying the items individually.  Remember there is execution overhead, just in calling and returning from `memcpy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working. Just because your debugger cannot see the data doesn't mean it's not there. What's happening is that your code says `uint8_t * pDestbuffer;` so your debugger thinks that pDestBuffer is just a pointer to a single byte, so that's what it shows. You know however that it's actually a pointer to an array.

There may be some way of telling your debugger that this is an array so you can see all the data. For instance, one debugger I know would let you type in `pStructure->pDestBuffer,4` to say show me four bytes not just one.

Comment: Another way, is to print `pStructure->pDestBuffer[0]`, `pStructure->pDestBuffer[1]`, and so on

Comment: `pDestBuffer,4` -> just GOLD! thanks for that. Your point is similar to cashcows and accurate. There was a bug in my output, and because of the debug I thought everything was wrong. Now I know it's not, however my `memcopy` results in a wrong content for pDest - but this might be a result of bad subroutine calls, which I am examining right now.

Answer (score 2):

I think "best practice" is not to mix C++ and C code.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::array<char, len> buffer;
std::size_t n = 5;
std::vector<char> dest; // if n is dynamic
dest.reserve(n); // "performance"
std::copy(begin(buffer), buffer + n, std::back_inserter(dest));

// or even shorter
std::vector<char> dest{begin(buffer), buffer + n};
```

Comment: @Jook Please notice that this uses C++11, but you can easily rewrite it not to.

Answer (score 1):

boost libraries is C++. Is this C or C++?

You say C in the title and your code is C but C++ is really a different language, with a different writing style.

What do you mean by "see all the slots"? If you are referring to Microsoft IDE, what you called unit8* which you probably mean `uint8_t *` or similar, is a pointer and it might interpret it as a null-terminated string but more likely just a pointer (due to its sign) and shows what it points to, rather than the start of an array.

Comment: I have one library, which is in C, which uses a wrapper to communicate - currently I am working on a boost-wrapper (C++) for windows/linux - later there might be one for a microcontroller, which would be in C - so both, C and C++ solutions are fine.

Comment: yes, I was referrring to MS IDE - there is a `typedef unsignet char unit8;` so your suggestion of null-term problematic is right, thanks for that.